# How do I cast from a concrete implementation to an interface in .NET

Tags: .net, generics

I am tweaking a library related to vehicle journeys that for the purpose of this question has two objects. I happen to be using vb, but that is pretty irrelevent to the discussion, other than I can express the generics in the text below without the editor eating the angle brackets

The first is a Trip object which implements an interface ITrip.   The second is a Hop object that implements an interface IHop. Both Trip and Hop objects have functions that are not part of the interface, but are used in the internal logic.

The ITrip interface has a read-only property, called Route, which is an IList(of IHop)

I want to implement that internally with a List(of Hop), the reason being is that the Trip objects logic needs to adjust the contents of the Hop using a Friend function.

I am having difficulty providing the code which implements the Route property, as I cannot (apparently) cast from the object to its interface. Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: Casting from a `Hop` to an `IHop` is trivial and implicit - it requires no syntax (although there *is* an explicit syntax, if you want). I suspect that what you are ***actually*** trying to do is to cast a `List<Hop>` / `IList<Hop>` to a `List<IHop>` / `IList<IHop>`. Would I be right? That is a *very* different question...

Comment: @MarcGravell I am trying to cast List<Hop> to IList<IHop>, at least that version is giving me a run time error when I try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting from `Hop` to `IHop` is trivial an implicit - no syntax is required. Likewise, casting from `List<Hop>` to `IList<Hop>` is trivial and implicit.

However, you cannot simply cast a `List<Hop>` to a `List<IHop>` (or `IList<...>`), because *they aren't compatible*. The compiler is stopping you from making a mistake: a `List<Hop>` can only contain `Hop`s (or subclasses of `Hop`) - however, a `List<IHop>` can contain my random `SomeClass : IHop`. If this cast *worked*, it would allow:

```
List<Hop> hops = ...
List<IHop> evil = hops;
evil.Add(new SomeClass()); // boom!

class SomeClass : IHop { } // but not a Hop
```

Basically, you will need to recreate a list of a different type. `ConvertAll` may be of use:

```
List<Hop> hops = ...
List<IHop> ihops = hops.ConvertAll(x => (IHop)x);
// or: IList<IHop> ihops = ...
```

You could also use (perhaps more convenient, but less efficient):

```
var ihops = hops.Cast<IHop>().ToList();
```

---

Additional: note that `IEnumerable<out T>` and `IReadOnlyList<out T>` **can** be cast directly, thanks to variance:

```
IReadOnlyList<Hop> hops = ...
IReadOnlyList<IHop> ihops = hops; // just works
```